# How can I ensure a spring quartz job executed sequentially?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have below trigger config:

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startNow()
    .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatSecondlyForever(5)).build();
```

And my job could possibly run more than 5 seconds.

Which means there could be chances that 2 job instances run at the same time.

Is there any policy I can enforce on quartz scheduler:

*if job is running, do not fire next one even if reach the repeat interval.*

Is it doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this annotation @DisallowConcurrentExecution.This should not allow executing of same instance of a Job
https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html